# What is the punishment for slapping someone's face?

Tags: punishment, violence

I have heard that slapping someone's face is forbiden in Islam. I want to know what is the punishment for it.

Answer (score 1):

Walakum assalam,

You are correct that it is prohibited to hit the face as the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, as narrated by Abu Hurayrah:

> “When any one of you fights, let him avoid (striking) the face.”
>
> (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, al-Fath, 5/215)

Now as far as your question, well **this would be considered a sin, with no specific punishment mentioned.** And usually when we say punishment, this just means a way too expiate the sin in this world rather than in the next. And this can only be done in an Islamic country after a trial.

Allah knows best.

Comment: One of my friend mentioned that Holy prophet (S.A.W.W) said He is not among us, if one slaps others face . Is that part true.

Comment: Not sure, but I haven't seen any hadeeth like that. Ask him for the hadeeth

Answer (score 0):

Narrated Abu Huraira:

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If somebody fights (or beats somebody) then he should avoid the face."

حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي مَالِكُ بْنُ أَنَسٍ، قَالَ وَأَخْبَرَنِي ابْنُ فُلاَنٍ، عَنْ سَعِيدٍ الْمَقْبُرِيِّ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَحَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّزَّاقِ، أَخْبَرَنَا مَعْمَرٌ، عَنْ هَمَّامٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِذَا قَاتَلَ أَحَدُكُمْ فَلْيَجْتَنِبِ الْوَجْهَ ‏"‏‏.‏
Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 2559
In-book reference    : Book 49, Hadith 41
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 3, Book 46, Hadith 734

there are more hadith in sahee muslim and bukhari authenticated by sheikh Albani